# Submit form post to hubspot

Tags: c#, html, .net, orchardcms

I have this form (I put the code below), and I need to add a button to submit the form via POST to the url of hubspot, any idea please...

```
@model OxfordEconomics.Users.ViewModels.CreateTrialUserHubspotViewModel
@using OxfordEconomics.Users.ViewModels;

 @using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("FreeTrialForm","FreeTrial", new { area = "OxfordEconomics.Users" }))) {
 <div>
             <div class="span12">
                <h1>@T("Free trial registration form")</h1>
                <p>@T("Please fill out the form below to request a free    trial, or ") <a href="/about-us/sales-and-service/inquiries">@T("contact a    service representative")</a>. </p>
                <p class="required-fields"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign red-icon"></i>: Required fields</p>

            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    <i class="icon-exclamation-sign red-icon" title="Required field"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                    <i class="icon-exclamation-sign red-icon"    title="Required field"></i>
                </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8 offset1">
                <button type="submit" name="submit.Filter"      value="@T("Filter")">@T("Apply")</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a plain form tag instead of the antiforgery helper call.

Comment: Could you bring me an example please?!